# Temple bell : Animal horn for ringing

Tags: temple

In a temple (Shri Raam Temple, Jaysingpur, Dist. Kolhapur, Maharashtra, India, to be exact), I have seen the bell having a piece of "deere horn" 
 (सींग in hindi) tied inside to strike and ring it.
What might be the reason?
Is there any ancient reference for this?

Comment: A picture would help us. Did you ask the temple authorities regarding this?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The place is not near to me now sadly (I have edited the Q to include the place name). I inquired about it. But the person there did not know why.

Comment: What is deere horn? Can you try searching something similar from the web? I found this one. Is it the same? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p50H.jpg

Comment: @Sarvabhouma you are right. A short stick is made from horn (सींग in hindi) of animal (i.e. Deere).